# how to setup cron job to run map reduce?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have three map reduce jobs and need to configure as a cron job.

I tried with creating cron job to run mapreduce but its not working. I mean map reduce job run is not initiated.

Please help in setting up cron job to run map reduce job. I can use Oozie for setting up a workflow job but wanted to use cronjob only.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use Oozie for MapReduce jobs scheduling. There is a lot of work done for you - workflows, data dependencies, monitoring. You can start with simple cron-like scenario and then extend without big reengineering. See https://github.com/yahoo/oozie/wiki/Oozie-Coord-Use-Cases for examples.